# Paramiko/SSH on Kivy Android App, possible?

Tags: android, python, paramiko

I've created a Kivy app that connects to several raspberry pi's via SSH, using paramiko. On my virtual environment and regular environment, the app works as it should. When I build the app with buildozer and package the APK, it will crash immediately when run. If I remove paramiko from the require line in the buildozer.spec file, and remove the import in the kivy app, it works (without the SSH functions...). I've also tried adding internet permissions to the app, didn't make a difference. Are paramiko/kivy/buildozer compatible with paramiko?